# How to check if a string starts with a specified string?

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if a string starts with `http`. How can I do this check?

```
$string1 = 'google.com';
$string2 = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Comment: Since it's such a widely used framework, it's worth mentioning that if you're using Laravel, you have the `starts_with` and `ends_with` helper functions available to you.

Comment: We can remove some comments from here since are answers, added as comments - also somehow already mentioned in the already existing answers.

Comment: Somehow on my server `str_starts_with` is a string (`"str_starts_with"`) and not a function. Any idea on what to do there? I'm on PHP 8.0.0…

Answer (score 1250, accepted):

### PHP 8 or newer:

Use the [**str_starts_with**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-starts-with.php) function:

```
str_starts_with('http://www.google.com', 'http')
```

### PHP 7 or older:

Use the [**substr**](https://www.php.net/manual/function.substr.php) function to return a part of a string.

```
substr( $string_n, 0, 4 ) === "http"
```

If you're trying to make sure it's not another protocol. I'd use `http://` instead, since https would also match, and other things such as http-protocol.com.

```
substr( $string_n, 0, 7 ) === "http://"
```

And in general:

```
substr($string, 0, strlen($query)) === $query
```

Comment: There is no need to hardcodede string length as said below if your needle is a variable. Just use substr( $string, 0, strlen($query) ) === $query.

Comment: Be careful when using multibyte utf8 strings! mb_substr is your friend

Comment: You are not required to use `mb_*` functions when you use `substr($string, 0, strlen($query)) === $query`

Comment: strpos solution from awgy uses fewer resources..

Comment: strpos version is better since you don't need sto store off the string you're checking or duplicate the code that accesses it.

Comment: @CoR And therefore, `mb_strlen` is also your friend!

Comment: `0, 3` Checks the first 4 characters, if I am correct. So, this will make sure that the test doesn't get a `true` return just because it had `http` somewhere in the domain.

Comment: Should the first line of this answer be `0, 3`, not `0, 4`?

Comment: @JesseSteele it's position, length and not start position, end position

Comment: Per the [str_starts_with RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/add_str_starts_with_and_ends_with_functions), the most CPU and memory efficient way to generically check if a string starts with another string prior to PHP 8 is `strncmp($haystack, $needle, strlen($needle)) === 0`.

Answer (score 825):

Use [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
if (strpos($string2, 'http') === 0) {
   // It starts with 'http'
}
```

Remember the three equals signs (`===`). It will not work properly if you only use two. This is because `strpos()` will return `false` if the needle cannot be found in the haystack.

Comment: It’s not necessary to search the whole string (`strpos` stops if the needle is found or the end is reached) if you just need to look at a specific position.

Comment: Which is trivial for short strings, but I'll upvote your substr() suggestion.

Comment: please use substr instead, as strpos searches the entire haystack for the needle, while substr just checks the beginning (which is most faster for long strings)

Comment: As Gumbo says, there is no performance advantage to substr. Use strpos() because it does not require you to hardcode a string length as a parameter, reducing errors.

Comment: @doublemarked No, there *is* a performance advantage to `substr`, which was Gumbo's point. Sure, if the needle is found at the start of the string, `strpos` will return early, but if it's *not* found, it will needlessly search the entire string. There's a tradeoff here; `strpos` reduces the chance of an error-causing typo, but `substr` theoretically ought to perform better, and I guess that could conceivably matter if your haystack was some enormous string, like the text of a novel. I always use `strpos` for the reason you gave, but I've upvoted both answers; `substr` might have its place.

Comment: I am sorry to resurrect the old thread, just wanted to say that this is so far the cleanest and most elegant solution to my point of view.

Comment: This is a minor quibble, but the backwards comparison style is anti-intuitive. I'd recommend editing the answer to use the regular comparison order.  (There used to be a trivial reason some programmers did that for a period of time, but it's not necessary.)  It's more readable and intuitive as "if (strpos($string2, 'http') === 0) ...

Comment: substr() generates garbage, whereas strpos() does not. Unless your string is VERY LONG, the integer return of strpos() beats the generated garbage of substr() for performance.

Comment: @orrd Hmmm... yeeeees, a yoda condition; unnecessary, it is. hrrrrm, Use it, you should not.

Comment: Best solution for now

Comment: Would substr not perform worse because it creates a copy of the string, which is a memory allocation?

Comment: To your micro-performance concerns about `substr` searching the entire string - just add an explicit offset: `strpos($string2, 'http', 0) === 0`, then it'll search from the start of the string only.

Comment: @mindplay.dk 0 is the default, and is only start position, not end.

Comment: Although not applicable to a function return, when comparing variables to values - backwards comparisons do offer one great advantage.  It's impossible to make an accidental variable assignment when writing them backwards.  If missing an equals sign, $a = 0 is an assignment 0 = $a is not.  I always argued against them until it was presented to me in this way.

Answer (score 135):

There is also the [`strncmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strncmp.php) function and [`strncasecmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strncasecmp.php) function which is perfect for this situation:

```
if (strncmp($string_n, "http", 4) === 0)
```

In general:

```
if (strncmp($string_n, $prefix, strlen($prefix)) === 0)
```

The advantage over the `substr()` approach is that `strncmp()` just does what needs to be done, without creating a temporary string.

Comment: strncmp() is good because it doesn't generate garbage, like substr() does. It's also better than strpos() because it doesn't need to scan the entire string. It's less convenient in that you have to actually hard-code or calculate the length of the prefix, and if you get this wrong/change it later, the function may stop working.

Comment: Wow there are lots of answers out there to this simple problem. I've chosen yours as the best: simply return strncmp($url, 'http', 4) === 0. Lots of string functions to chose from in the manual, but this is the obvious fit for the problem and I'd hazard a guess it's the best performing.

Comment: This is really nice answer, and is really exactly does what is asked is to compare start of strings, not find, compare. Don't know why this isn't selected answer or have so few upvotes.

Comment: this should definitely be the fastest way

Answer (score 48):

You can use a simple regex (updated version from user *viriathus* as `eregi` is deprecated)

```
if (preg_match('#^http#', $url) === 1) {
    // Starts with http (case sensitive).
}
```

or if you want a case insensitive search

```
if (preg_match('#^http#i', $url) === 1) {
    // Starts with http (case insensitive).
}
```

**Regexes allow to perform more complex tasks**

```
if (preg_match('#^https?://#i', $url) === 1) {
    // Starts with http:// or https:// (case insensitive).
}
```

Performance wise, you don't need to create a new string (unlike with substr) nor parse the whole string if it doesn't start with what you want. You will have a performance penalty though the 1st time you use the regex (you need to create/compile it).

> This extension maintains a global per-thread cache of compiled regular
>   expressions (up to 4096).
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pcre.php

Comment: regex is much more complex, then a strpos or substr operation, so it costs more performance and in this task it is definetly not needed

Comment: @Sharpy35: maybe, but I don't think of performance cost unless I've detected that it is making the system too slow. Avoid premature optimizations. Also regex is so much more powerful, it's really something developers should know.

Comment: i didnt said that i dont know regex ;) i am just avoiding to use it whenever i can :)

Comment: I think it's unfair to discuss "Performance wise" when this is the least performant method

Comment: Main problem with a regex in that case is probably going to be that it is quite error-prone (need to appropriately escape characters f.i.)

Comment: This is definitly better way to handle: the scope is to see if a string start with "http". This is related with parse_url function that cannot handle some particular case. The regex is the correct way to create your own function

Comment: @Berkant Haha, I totally agree and I usually try to avoid RegEx(p)s whenever I can, but **sadly**, this seems to be the **most elegant and readable solution :(** And code maintability turned out to be a big treasure.

Comment: To my surprise (at least on PHP 7.3.6), this actually seems to be faster than strpos! (and it is only a little bit slower than substr)

Answer (score 15):

You can check if your string starts with http or https using the small function below.

```
function has_prefix($string, $prefix) {
   return substr($string, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix;
}

$url   = 'http://www.google.com';
echo 'the url ' . (has_prefix($url, 'http://')  ? 'does' : 'does not') . ' start with http://';
echo 'the url ' . (has_prefix($url, 'https://') ? 'does' : 'does not') . ' start with https://';
```

Comment: If anyone reads answer this then the ternaries `? true : false` are redundant and can be removed completely

Comment: Here we can use the "===" strict check, but in that case we would duplicate this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2790919/3451846