# Regex, PHP pregmatch make function how to return true if string start with start_to_date

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: How to check if a string starts with a specified string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790899/php-how-to-check-if-a-string-starts-with-a-specified-string)

I am struggling to create a function to check this string starting from start_to_date or not,  below is my implement.

```
$string = 'start_to_date-blablablabla';
if(cek_my_str($string)){
   echo "String is OK";
}

// tes again
$string2 = 'helloworld-blablablabla';
if(cek_my_str($string2)){
   echo "String not OK";
}

function cek_my_str($str){
   // how code to return true if $str is string which start with start_to_date
}
```

Thanx.

Comment: Please do research before asking questions that have been asked and answered again or to which the answer is easy to find in search engines.

Comment: @AlanIchal; Your tone is suck boy!

Comment: http://php.net/strpos - can we close the question now? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, people got down voted cos of this suck-manner boy!

Comment: @AlanIchal: You need to **BE NICE** here on Stack Overflow. "Your answer is suck man" is not considered "nice".

Answer (score 3):

To do it with Regex, you would do:

```
return preg_match('/^start_to_date/', $str);
```

Key reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

However, the [PHP Manual for preg_match states](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

> Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster.

---

By the way, you should look into unit testing: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/

This is a way of encapsulating exactly what you are doing in reusable tests.

Comment: And why is the question down voted too?  It is very basic level but people have to start somewhere, right?

Comment: Re: question getting downvoted, okay I get that. Re: my answer getting downvoted, and your comment on the question (which I don't have enough rep to reply to) "people got downvoted because they suggest overly complicated solutions instead of simply suggesting strpos"  Well the question **stated** `preg_match`, so I believe that this is a starting point, not an ending point.  Clearly there is something after the "start_to_date" token, which in likelihood will need to be further parsed.  It seems like this person is studying regular expressions, so telling them to use `strpos` is invalid.

Comment: Anyway if it's a duplicate, why not just mark it as such?

Comment: Well the title stated both "regex" and "preg_match" so I'm not making any assumptions.

Comment: So you did, voted. (for the record at least lol)

Answer (score 3):

In this case the best thing to do is:

```
if(strpos($string, 'start_to_date') === 0) { ... }
```

`strpos()` checks if 'start_to_date' is on position 0 (beginning)

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
function cek_my_str($str){
    return preg_match('/^start_to_date/', $str)
}
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: OK this solved. tnx man. I just add if !preg_match blabla return false and default return true. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function cek_my_str($str){
   $find = 'start_to_date';
   $substr = substr($str, 0, strlen($find));
   if($substr == $find){
    return true;
   }else{
    return false;
   }
}
```