# Wild card in PHP value equal parameter

Tags: php, wildcard

In SQL there is the `LIKE` parameter that you can put in to have a wild card for values such as: `LIKE %value%`. How would I be able to do that with, say, a PHP if statement?

```
$value = "value-";

$post = $_POST['retrievedVal'];

if($value.% == $post)
{
   echo "true";
}
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790899/php-how-to-check-if-a-string-starts-with-a-specified-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is none, but don't worry there is a way to achieve the same with `strpos()`

just use the following if statement:

```
if(false !== strpos($post, $value)){
    // you thing to do
}
```

*beware strpos could return 0, so the explicit comparison is needed*

Comment: uhm, i believe you mean strpos()

Comment: Sorry, you are right edited the post, sorry. Was with my mind some where else .. thanks again