# How to check if a variable starts with a specific string?

Tags: php

I was looking and found [How to check if variables starts with specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790899/php-how-to-check-if-a-string-starts-with-a-specified-string) & [How to chech if a variable contains specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-specific-words) but, I don't get it.

Which one could I use to check if a variable **STARTS** with a specific string just like a MYSQL LIKE WHERE CLAUSE:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'string%'
```

Comment: `preg_match('/^string.*$/', $sString)` ? - though it's probably not worth the RegExp overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this, to match for any length string. Instead of hardcoding the string and it's length.

```
$string = "string to test";
$testfor = "strin";
if(substr( $string, 0, strlen($testfor) ) === $teststr) {
      echo "Match";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(substr($string, 0, 5) === "String") {
# Do code
} else {
# Error
}
```

Easy enough for simple strings.