# unset 54 out of 55 session variables in PHP

Tags: php

I have `55 session variables` and want to `unset 54` of them. They all begin with **sv**

and the one that I want to keep begins with **nb**

I tried to do this but to no avail. Does anybody have any suggestions?

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $val)
{
    if ($key !== 'nb')
    {
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
}
```

I was thinking to use a `loop` to `unset` them instead of typing `unset(variable) 54 times`

Comment: use ````sub_string```` to check if 'nb' is at the begin of the string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790899/php-how-to-check-if-a-string-starts-with-a-specified-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `substr()` to find the first two letters and exclude 'nb'.

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $val)
{

    if (substr($key,0,2) !== 'nb')
    {

        unset($_SESSION[$key]);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that string begins from `nb`

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $val)
    if (strpos($key,'nb') !== 0) unset($_SESSION[$key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $val)
{
    if (substr($key,0,2) !== 'nb')
    {
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
}
```