# How to check if a string starts with another string - PHP

Tags: php

I want test if a `String1` start by a `string2` in `PHP`

I found this question:
[How to check if a string starts with a specified string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790899/how-to-check-if-a-string-starts-with-a-specified-string)

But I want do it inside an `if` condition - not in a function.
I did it like this but I'm not sure:

```
if(startsWith($type_price,"repair")) {

do something

}
```

Can you please correct me if it's false?

Comment: You can perform any operation you like in an `if` statement. So you can just aswell use `substr()` as in your linked example in your `if` condition.

Comment: PHP 8.0 introduces new methods for this job `str_starts_with`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64160081/7082164

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using `strpos` function can be achieved.

```
if (strpos($yourString, "repair") === 0) {
    //Starts with it
}
```

---

Using `substr` can work too:

```
if (substr($yourstring, 0, strlen($startString)) === $startString) {
    //It starts with desired string
}
```

For multi-byte strings, consider using functions with `mb_` prefix, so `mb_substr`, `mb_strlen`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (substr($string,0,strlen($stringToSearchFor)) == $stringToSearchFor) {
     // the string starts with the string you're looking for
} else {
     // the string does NOT start with the string you're looking for
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 8.0 there is method [`str_starts_with`](https://www.php.net/str_starts_with) implemented:

```
if (str_starts_with($type_price, "repair")) {
    //do something
}
```