# Increment data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here's my code

```
    $receipt = $_POST['receipt'];
    $invid = $_POST['invid'];
    // $receipt = intval($receipt);
    // $invid = intval($invid);

    $newreceipt = 0;
    $GTextension = 'GT-';
    $UTextension = 'UT-';
    $rec_type = array(1472,1416,9752,1417,1500);
    $last_receipt = $this->ion_auth->getLastReceipt($receipt);
    if($last_receipt->num_rows() > 0){
        if($receipt == 1){
            $newreceipt = $last_receipt->row()->inv_cno+1;
        }
        elseif($receipt == 2){
            $newreceipt = $last_receipt->row()->inv_cno+1;
        }
        elseif($receipt == 3){
            $newreceipt = $last_receipt->row()->inv_cno+1;
        }
        elseif($receipt == 4){
            $newreceipt = $UTextension.(++$last_receipt->row()->inv_cno);
        }
        else if($receipt == 5){
            $newreceipt = $GTextension.(++$last_receipt->row()->inv_cno);
        }
    }

    $this->ion_auth->update_receipt($invid,$receipt,$newreceipt);

    $return = array('dr_no' => $newreceipt);

    echo json_encode($return);
```

Now the output of this code is like this
if i choose `==4` then it it is like this

`UT-1418` it's correct.

then if i choose again `==4` the problem exist because it is now like this
`UT-UT-1419`. It's incrementing also the extension. All i want to increment is the data which is `-1419`

Can someone help me please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it like this

```
$prefix = 'UT-'; 
elseif($receipt == 4){
       if (substr($UTextension, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix) {
                $UTextension = substr($UTextension, strlen($prefix));
                $newreceipt = $UTextension. (++$last_receipt->row()->inv_cno);
       }
 }
```

Thanks Lorenzo S

Answer (score 0):

If `$receipt === 4` you are executing this:

`$newreceipt = $UTextension.(++$last_receipt->row()->inv_cno);`

and then you are saving the value in the DB with `$this->ion_auth->update_receipt($invid,$receipt,$newreceipt);`.

So, now, the database contains "UT-*something*".

Now, if you execute this simple code in PHP, you will probably get the point:

```
$test = "UT-10";
++$test;
echo "$test\n";
```

It will output `UT-11`.
You can take a look at some [official documentation to understand why this works like this](http://php.net/manual/it/language.types.type-juggling.php).

So, what happens is that the next time that `$receipt === 4`, you perform the same code:
`$newreceipt = $UTextension.(++$last_receipt->row()->inv_cno);`

that is equivalent to `"UT-" . "UT-*something*"`.

And so the unwanted result.

Now, the solution is up to your needs:
If `inv_cno` has to be an integer, you just save the integer and you calculate back the `"prefix-" . inv_cno` in the code.

Otherwise, you should just check if the `$last_receipt->row()->inv_cno` already [has a prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790899/how-to-check-if-a-string-starts-with-a-specified-string) in it, in order to understand if you have to add/change it or not.

EDIT --- after user comments.

Now that we now it is a varchar, assuming that the prefix is always a 3 characters string ("UT-", "GT-" and so on), you can create something like this.
According to your example, I assume that inv_cno can already have or not have a prefix.
And I assume that the admissible prefixes are "UT-" and "GT-".

I will write you an example here to make you understand my point, then you will have to integrate it in your code :)

```
<?php

function get_new_receipt($inv_cno, $extension) {
  $prefix_len = 3;
  $admissible_prefixes = array("UT-", "GT-");
  $inv_cno++;
  if (strlen($inv_cno) <= $prefix_len) {
    return $extension . $inv_cno;
  }
  $current_prefix = substr($inv_cno, 0, $prefix_len);
  if ($current_prefix === $extension) {
    return $inv_cno;
  }

  return $extension . substr($inv_cno, $prefix_len);
}


$test = "UT-10";

$test = get_new_receipt($test, "UT-");
echo "$test\n";

$test = get_new_receipt($test, "UT-");
echo "$test\n";

$test = get_new_receipt($test, "GT-");
echo "$test\n";
```

*P.S.: Anyway, as a side note, it's not so safe to perform this kind of math over strings. But that's another story.*

Comment: `inv_cno` is a varchar sir.

Comment: i'll be honest. It's kind of hard to implement . I'm sorry but I will try.

Comment: and could you explain the code more sir so i can understand it clearly