# Compare first 4 characters of a string PHP

Tags: php

The problem is with this line:

```
if $var LIKE '1800%';
```

and I'm not sure how to fix it.  Thanks.

```
<?php 
//check to see if account number is like 1800*
if (isset($_POST['acct_number'])) {
$var = $_POST['acct_number'];
    if $var LIKE '1800%'; {
        //stop the code
        exit;
    } else {
        echo 'normal account number';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to mix MySQL and PHP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a string starts with a specified string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790899/how-to-check-if-a-string-starts-with-a-specified-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [startsWith() and endsWith() functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/startswith-and-endswith-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need PHP not MySQL.  For `1800%` just check that it is found at position `0`:

```
if(strpos($var, '1800') === 0) {
    //stop the code
    exit;
} else {
    echo 'normal account number';
}
```

If it can occur anywhere like `%1800%` then:

```
if(strpos($var, '1800') !== false) {
    //stop the code
    exit;
} else {
    echo 'normal account number';
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you!  

 if(strpos($var, '1800') === 0) {

Answer (score 3):

Another way could be to use [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
if (strpos($var, '1800') === 0) {
   // var starts with '1800'
}
```

Comment: Yes ... perfect!  Thank you.

Comment: @Blondie mark any of the answers as accepted whichever is working perfectly for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `substr` function to get first 4 characters and compare it with `1800`.

```
if(substr($var, 0, 4) == '1800')
{
 // your code goes here.
}
``
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular expression for this `preg_match('/^1800.+/', $search, $matches);`

Comment: May want to use ? instead of + just incase its a 4 char string "1800".