# Allow Only add link from specific websites

Tags: php

```
 <input type="url" id="url" class="form-control image_url">
```

I need to allow users add only links from popular drive sites like google drive or one drive

```
    $url_allowed = array("https://drive.google.com/", "https://1drv.ms/"); //Add Allowed Website list Here

    if(!$url_allowed){
        echo 'invalid link';
        return;
    }
```

What is the right method to do that ?

Comment: First give the HTML input element a `name` attribute, for example `name="url"`or the data will never be sent to the server by the browser! _I assume there is a `<form>` wrapped around that `<input>`_

Comment: Then look up `in_array()` in the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: It's better to just have the hostname in your array `drive.google.com` etc without the protocol or any trailing slashes. Then you can use [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the hostname of the URL the user entered and use `in_array()` to see if it exists in the array

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you 

`   $url_allowed = array("https://drive.google.com/", "https://1drv.ms/"); //Add Allowed Website list Here
`
it just allow this domains only , if i pu a link like  `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-C_W3aFokd5GGA6riBHA8LXu_N1w0LNk/view?usp=sharing`
but the system reject it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop all possible links and check if provided link starts with it:

```php
$whitelist = ['https://drive.google.com/', ...];
$link = $_POST['link'] ?? null;
$isValid = false;

if (empty($link)) {
    throw new Exception('Missing link');
}

foreach ($whitelist as $whitelistLink) {
    if (str_starts_with($link, $whitelistLink)) {
        $isValid = true;
 
        break;
    }
}

if (!$isValid) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid link');
}
```

Comment: Thank you , it is for php 8 , i am using version 7.3

Comment: @Mohammad the only thing that is PHP 8 here, is `str_starts_with`. The manual has a replacement for lower PHP versions in the user comments already, and typing something like "str_starts_with for php 7" into Google, could also have lead you to https://stackoverflow.com/q/2790899/1427878 in no time.

Comment: @Mohammad Replace `str_starts_with` with `str_pos($link, $whitelistLink) === 0`