# Issue with adding a basic IF-statement to a code snippet

Tags: php

I'm trying to add a basic IF-statement to a PHP code snippet but my PHP knowledge is very limited and I didn't have much success until now (I tried different variations on IF-statements which I found in other code snippets).

The company that originally created the code explained me in the code snippet where to add the IF-statement, what kind of IF-statement I need (if the coupon code begins with 'affiliate-credit' return true) and also told me I should work with the variable called `$coupon` (this variable contains the name of the coupon).

Here is the code snippet:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: AffiliateWP - Block WooCommerce Assigned Affiliate Coupon If Affiliate Purchasing
 * Plugin URI: http://affiliatewp.com
 * Description: Prevents assigned affiliate coupon codes from being used on the WooCommerce order if the affiliate is the purchaser
 * Author: AffiliateWP
 * Author URI: https://affiliatewp.com
 * Version: 1.0
 */
/**
 * Make assigned coupon invalid if customer is an affiliate.
 */
function affwp_custom_block_affiliate_coupon_if_customer_affiliate( $condition, $coupon, $vars ) {
    
    if ( ! function_exists( 'affiliate_wp' ) ) {
        return $condition; // Make sure AffiliateWP is installed, otherwise just return.
    }
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    
    if ( empty( $current_user_id ) ) {
        return $condition; // Probably not logged in, just return.
    }
    if ( ! affwp_is_affiliate( $current_user_id ) ) {
        return $condition; // Not an affiliate, just return.    
    }
    
    if ( empty( $coupon->id ) ) {
        $coupon = affwp_get_coupon( $coupon->code );
// Add IF statement here that if the coupon code begins with 'affiliate-credit' return true to allow store credit coupons.
        if ( false !== $coupon && affwp_get_affiliate_user_id( $coupon->affiliate_id ) === $current_user_id ) {
            return false; // Dynamic coupon assigned to this affiliate, disallow the coupon.
        }
    }
    $is_tracked_coupon = get_post_meta( $coupon->id, 'affwp_discount_affiliate', true );
    if ( affwp_get_affiliate_user_id( $is_tracked_coupon ) === $current_user_id ) {
        return false; // Coupon assigned to this affiliate, disallow the coupon.
    }
    return $condition;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_is_valid', 'affwp_custom_block_affiliate_coupon_if_customer_affiliate', 10, 3 );
```

To give you some more info about what this code snippet does:

- This code snippet blocks affiliates to use discount coupon codes for new clients themselves (because they already got a discount when registering)

What I'm trying to accomplish by adding that IF-statement:

- Add an exception to the code snippet so that coupons for which the coupon code starts with the text 'affiliate-credit' are not blocked (so an affiliate is allowed to use that coupon).

I understood it should be a very easy line of code to write for a PHP developer but I didn't have much success until now since my PHP knowledge is very limited.

Comment: Please put a [mre] in the question itself, not a link to an external site.

Comment: @Barmar Can you please check the question again? I did an edit like you requested almost a week ago. Thank you.

Comment: What did you try and where are you stuck, exactly? Show your attempt and explain what difficulty you encountered. Whether the solution is simple or not, this site isn't a replacement for learning the basics and making an attempt. If you need someone to write all your code for you, hire a programmer for money. Stackoverflow is for fellow programmers to collaborate and assist each other with programming problems. The questions should be just as useful as the answers, not merely requests for free labour. See also the [tour] and [ask]. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per the instruction you need to check if the coupon code begins with 'affiliate-credit' or not. If yes then the IF statement should return true.

To do so you need to check `$coupon` if it begins with 'affiliate-credit' or not. [As we can see the value of `$coupon` is set by `affwp_get_coupon( $coupon->code )` function]

The following might help you achieve this goal:
[How to check if a string starts with a specified string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790899/how-to-check-if-a-string-starts-with-a-specified-string)

If you can share some sample output values of `$coupon` here, that would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Kaysar, thank you for your reply!
An example output value of `$coupon` beginning with 'affiliate-credit' is for example 'affiliate-credit-202308151438_44'. It can also have other output values like 'coupon123' or 'DADJGDLFSL".
It would be great if you could help me further with the code. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @LukeBo, it's my pleasure. However, as per your example to check if it is starting with 'affiliate-credit' or not I have already shared the link in the answer where it is explained how to check it. Hope you have managed to solve it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Kaysar Unfortunately my PHP knowledge is very limited. It's still too complicated for me. Like I understood from the company that originally created the code, the extra code I need to get the result we need for this is only 1 or 2 lines max. According to them a very easy job for a PHP developer. Could you maybe provide that piece of code? I would be very grateful for this!