Facebook sharing with a twist
I would like to know, if there is such possibility as to point to a specific URL for FB sharing with its specific og metatags values when I click the share button (I am using ShareThis), BUT the website would lead to another URL containing anchor after clicking the post on FB?
The reason for this is that I have webpage which is basically just one dynamic page containing several sections which corresponds to different articles, thus the page has the same og metatags for all of them if I would share it as normally.
So I come to possible solution to point to a .php file which basically contains only HEAD og metatags for the specific article but would open that one-page site with the anchor in the URL that would make the site jump to the appropriate section once clicked on FB. I hope you do understand what I mean - english lng is not my native one, sorry.
Now the question is how to actually do it? How to make a specific .php file containing just the required og metatags would actually open another url containing acnhor after clicking the post in the FB? I tried redirection but it would collect the og metatags from the main one page site instead, which is wrong, of course.
IS THIS EVEN POSSIBLE, AND IF SO, THEN HOW?
This is the HTML code of that sharer php file I use:
<?php
// UPDATE: Even with this newly added suggestion by @CBroe it still does not work and FB Debugger see it as "broken" code
if((strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'facebookexternalhit/1.1') !== 0)) {
    header('Location: https://www.somedomainhere.com/#someAnchorHere01'), exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sk">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        
        <title>Socnets sharer</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Sharer temp page." />
        
        <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.somedomainhere.com/php/_socnetshare-someNameHere01.php" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="SOME TITLE HERE" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="SOME DESCRIPTION HERE." />
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.somedomainhere.com/img/some-image-here-fb.jpg" />
        <meta property="og:image:width" content="1920" />
        <meta property="og:image:height" content="1080" />
        <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>

FB Debugger see all the parameters correctly - correct image is loaded, correct title and desc are there, everything, I just need to know/understand how to make it actually opening different url once clicked as a post on FB that is all...and redirecting it is not, as it automatically take all those og tags from the wrong page then.

You need to implement an exception, so that you do not redirect the Facebook scraper. It can be recognized via the User-Agent it sends, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler

Thank you for the answer, but I am prolly not that advanced to be able extracting the real info from this "just like that". So could you, please, post some example answer so I would understand it practically and also could tick it as the correct answer if it would work.

You find the User Agent in $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']. Check if that value starts with facebookexternalhit/1.1 (that covers the first two mentioned User Agent strings. The third one you can probably ignore, unless Facebook product catalogs were involved in what you are doing, but it doesn't sound like it.) Don't forget to use the Facebook sharing debugger to clear the cache, after you made changes. (And already existing post on FB will likely not change their behavior retroactively, so you'll need to make new ones to test, or refresh the share attachment if existing posts via the UI.)

Sorry, still not wiser, I guess I will update my post adding the HTML code of the sharing php and if you can, you could actually show me the practical usage, cos this what you are writing...I have no clue where to put it or whatever. Can we do it that way? Anyway, I am updating my post now...

Put this at the very start of the document: <?php if(!str_starts_with($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'facebookexternalhit/1.1')) { header('Location: ...'), exit; } ?> (If you are not using PHP 8 yet, then figure out what to use instead of str_starts_with to perform this check. And the Location header needs to contain the URL you want to redirect the human visitors to.)

Aha, this is much more understandable for me now, I guess I got it, but unfortunately I am still on PHP 5.4.17, so...anyway, I am gonna add that code and see what happens.

I tried to use this instead of the str_starts_with() but it does not work: if(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0) != 'facebookexternalhit/1.1') {  header('Location: https://www.somedomeainhere.com/#someAnchroHere01'), exit; }

substr starting from position 0, is of course still the full string. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2790899/1427878

ah, sure, I see...so I have to count all the individual letters in that 'facebookexternalhit/1.1' string, OK, gonna try it.

So I updated it to this, but it still does not work as a substitution for the str_stars_with(): if(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 23) != 'facebookexternalhit/1.1') {  header('Location: https://www.somedomeainhere.com/#someAnchroHere01'), exit; }

"so I have to count all the individual letters in that 'facebookexternalhit/1.1' string" - no you don't, that thread contains more than one possible solution - and the strpos one is much more convenient to use here.

Ehm, wouldn't it be much easier and quicker if you could please kindly show me the correct version of my substitution for the str_starts_with()? :-)`

Now I have this - still does not work: if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'facebookexternalhit/1.1') != 0) {  header('Location: https://www.somedomeainhere.com/#someAnchroHere01'), exit; }

"but it still does not work" - did you take into account what I said, regarding that you need to re-scrape the URL, and that it won't affect already existing posts ...?

??? I am testing every update to this code directly at FB Debug online tool...thus scraping the previous ones of course.

Not sure what you mean by "thus scraping the previous ones of course". Scraping updates what info Facebook has cached for the URL that you are trying to share. That does not affect already existing posts on Facebook, in which that URL was shared (unless the user that made the post, would manually refresh the share attachment via context menu.)

Why don't we still understand? I am telling you, that every change/uipdate to the code I do I check what info is parsed by the FB sharer directly on the Facebook Debugger tool - I am not checking any real posted stuff on FB itself. An dI am telling you it doe snot work as the FB Debugger tool see it as broken: no image loaded, no title, nor description, no url. If I omit you code all together and re-scrap the page it immediately gets all the correct values. Thus I think there is something wrong in my code where I tried to replace that str_starts_with() part as I am still on PHP 5.4.17.

...so what I am saying now is the question if it wouldn't be simplier if you could correct my wrong code from above that was trying to replace that str_stars_with() - uff, I think I am unable explkain it any more and further.

The test using strpos needs to use type-safe comparison. if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'facebookexternalhit/1.1') !== 0))

Don't you have typo in there? One missing "("? Anyway, it does not work still - FB Debugger see it still as broken no matter what.

Do a bit of debugging then ... Set $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = 'facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)'; first, and then check if your script reacts as expected - in your own browser. Once that has been verified, log the value that $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] contains, when your URL is actually requested by the scraper, to verify what it actually contains.

No no, I just found out what was the problem with your code: you had another typo in there having header('Location: https://www.somedomeainhere.com/#someAnchorHere01'), instead of the correct header('Location: https://www.somedomeainhere.com/#someAnchorHere01'); - once I corrected this it seems to be working...or at least FB Debugger tool now shows everything is correct and working. But I will be sure only once I actually share it to FB some time later.

Now would you answer it as normal answer - post to my question, so I can tick you as the correct answer...or should I answer it myself mentioning you?

Feel free to write it up yourself, if you like.

OK, I will mantioning you there as the source of the correct answer - thank you.

@CBroe I just realized that this solution is JUST FOR THE FACEBOOK, but what about all the other social networks? Thus it brings me to reversed idea: wouldn't it be better to have positive condition that would check "IF the http user agent IS Mozilla THEN redirect" instead of now checking for the specific FB user agent. As there is zillions of social networks compared to some major browsers. For instance Firefox and Chrome both have word "Mozilla" in the beginnig of the string from $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], so now only to find out what the other major browsers have there...but how?

It turns out to be a typo in the original suggested code - which I just copy/paste as it was given/written to me - where there was "," instead of correct ";" in one specific line.
Anyway, big thanks to @CBroe who is the one coming up with the actual solution (I just found and corrected the typo, that is).
The working code is thus this one below:
<?php
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'facebookexternalhit/1.1') !== 0) {
    header('Location: https://www.somedomainhere.com/#someAnchorHere01');
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sk">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        
        <title>Socnets sharer</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Sharer temp page." />
        
        <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.somedomainhere.com/php/_socnetshare-someNameHere01.php" />
        
        <meta property="og:title" content="SOME TITLE HERE" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="SOME DESCRIPTION HERE." />
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.somedomainhere.com/img/some-image-here-fb.jpg" />
        <meta property="og:image:width" content="1920" />
        <meta property="og:image:height" content="1080" />
        <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>

EDIT
I just realized that above solution is made specifically for the Facebook, but what about all those zillions of other social networks? So I reversed the logic and now checking for the browser instead, thus updated and I guess more suitable code now looks like this:
<?php
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mozilla') === 0) {
    header('Location: https://www.somedomainhere.com/#someAnchorHere01');
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sk">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        
        <title>Socnets sharer</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Sharer temp page." />
        
        <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.somedomainhere.com/php/_socnetshare-someNameHere01.php" />
        
        <meta property="og:title" content="SOME TITLE HERE" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="SOME DESCRIPTION HERE." />
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.somedomainhere.com/img/some-image-here-fb.jpg" />
        <meta property="og:image:width" content="1920" />
        <meta property="og:image:height" content="1080" />
        <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>

